# Why JNI is preferred over Runtime and Process

Tags: java, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JNI vs Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782827/jni-vs-runtime-exec)

As I know, we can use the Java Native Interface (JNI) to let Java run native code. But I think we can use `Runtime` and `Process` interface to invoke the native executable instead. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752082/jni-or-runtime-exec?rq=1

Comment: Fine, then tell me how you're going to get a Windows hWnd by using Runtime and Process? Or call methods from the Windows dll's, user32.dll or kernal.dll?

Comment: I have read both these article,but still do not find my answer.I just wonder their scenario.Thx

Comment: A better question is why use JNI instead of JNA. You haven't answered my question above. How will you make calls inside of dll's of *any* type if there are no way to call them with Runtime and Process?

Comment: But,if i have the source of the dll,i think i can still use the jni to wrap it

Comment: A JNI wrapper is *not* an executable. You can't run it via Runtime and Process. And you have the Windows source code? Really??

Comment: So,the answer is that we can use the Process and Runtime interface when we do not have the source of the dll.Am i correct?thx

Comment: No, you're not correct. You use Process and Runtime if you want to run an application as a separate process by Java.

Comment: yes,i know that 'A JNI wrapper is not an executable'.i mean if i want to use something of the dll,i can use the jni method to wrap it and invoke it in my java code.

Comment: hah,i just say if.But anyway,i get ur meaning,thx

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, you CAN call method inside dll from Runtime. If you run a batch script that does something like (for example): rundll32.exe %windir%\system32\mshtml.dll,PrintHTML "C:\x.html". RTFM

Comment: @aviad: There are many things you can't do in a batch script that require JNI or JNA. Callbacks for one. RTFM.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, really? What about PUSHD/POPD for callbacks?